# Simmons-Smith Cyclopropanation and Sterics

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I know this is a Simmons-Smith reaction. Wikipedia tells me this:

> The Simmons–Smith reaction is generally subject to steric effects, and thus cyclopropanation usually takes place on the less hindered face.

Therefore, will the cyclopropane be added to the opposite side of the methyl group; i.e. will the cyclopropane group be drawn with dashes rather than wedges?

I understand that if the methyl group is not present then we would get equal amounts of two products, which are enantiomers (as shown by the second image)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the cyclopropane ring will be on the opposite side of the ring of the methyl group. If the methyl group of (R)-3-methylcyclohex-1-ene was not there, it would be just be cyclohexene, and there would only be one product (no stereoisomers). In the reaction with 1-methylcyclohex-1-ene, each side of the ring is equally hindered, and which is why the enantiomers are formed in equal amounts.